# selenium recognize key stroke and stop

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've made a software in which when you start it, it starts Selenium and begins with some tests, my question is:
In-case the user wishes to stop the software, what can I do in-order to stop it in the middle?(Preferably with key strokes)

Thanks :)

Comment: Bump~ Couldn't find an answer online

Comment: do you want to come out of execution if user wants to stop the software ? you can share your usecase , based on that we can provide you the optimistic solution.

Comment: Afraid I can't share it. If the users uses "Ctrl + C" I would like to stops selenium.